# Cordova 3.4.0 InAppBrowser Not Working

Tags: inappbrowser

I'm new to Cordova and JS and have been struggling with the InAppBrowser plug-in for Cordova 3.4.0 to work in iOS (Xcode v5.0.2).

The cordova project was built successfully using these command line commands:

```
cordova create InAppBrowserTest3-4 local.test InAppBrowser_Test3-4
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugins
[ 'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser' ]
```

www config file contains:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

Only these additional commands were added to the generated onDeviceReady method to exercise the InAppBrowser:

onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

```
//added these lines below
    alert('deviceReady');
    var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
    ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
    ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
    alert('end deviceReady');
}
```

When executed, the last alert isn't called and no browser is open. Similar code is running successfully using Cordova 2.9.0.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I've read through several similar posts but haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this, try the following:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

cd hello

cordova platform add android

cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

cordova build
```

Note the "cordova build" step, which creates the `platform/ios/www` directory where you can find the file `cordova_plugins.js` with the folder plugins correctly installed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. :-) I struggled with this and its great to have it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried manually adding in the data to `platforms/ios/www/plugins/cordova_plugins` but whenever I performed `run ios` it would be overwritten by the build process. What worked for me was doing `cordova platform remove ios` then `cordova platform add ios`.

This showed up in my cordova_plugins.js file:

```
{
    "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.inappbrowser",
    "clobbers": [
        "window.open"
    ]
},
```

And it stayed there. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I use the PhoneGap compile on the cloud. What I do is include the

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.2.4" />
```

into the xml config file. Make sure your cordova.js at the top of other javascript includes in the index.html. That should work.